# Count the rows in an aggregation result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following collection which represents a swipe record when a member goes to the gym. I want to return the rank of a member after the number of swipes in a given month.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "content" : {
        "Date_Key" : "",
        "TRANSACTION_EVENT_KEY" : "",
        "SITE_NAME" : "",
        "Swipe_DateTime" : "",
        "Gender" : "",
        "Post_Out_Code" : "",
        "Year_Of_Birth" : "",
        "Time_Key" : "",
        "MemberID_Hash" : "",
        "Member_Key_Hash" : "",
        "Swipes" : ""
    },
    "collection" : "observations"
}
```

I have the following aggregation which returns the members with a higher rank (thus, the members that have been to the gym more often)

```
collection
            .aggregate(
            [{$match: {"content.Swipe_DateTime": {$regex:"201602"}}},
            {$group: {_id: "$content.MemberID_Hash", count:{$sum: 1}}},
            {$sort: {count: 1}},
            {$match: {count: {$gte: user_swipes_month}}}],
            function(err,result) {
                console.log("User's Rank: ", result[0].count);
            });
```

but then my question is, how can i count the number or rows returned? I have tried doing another group by but I thought it wasn't correct given the result obtained.

```
collection
            .aggregate(
            [{$match: {"content.Swipe_DateTime": {$regex:"201602"}}},
            {$group: {_id: "$content.MemberID_Hash", count:{$sum: 1}}},
            {$sort: {count: 1}},
            {$match: {count: {$lte: user_swipes_month}}},
            {$group: {_id: null, count:{$sum: 1}}}],
            function(err,result) {
                console.log("User's Rank: ", result[0].count);
            });
```

Any ideas/suggestions how I might solve this?

Comment: What was not correct ? What is your expected output ? The last group will give you that total numbers of results returned.

Comment: May be, in the second query you are using $lte rather than $gte, as per your original problem statement.